# How to measure the closeness in the values of two vectors of different lengths

Tags: matlab, math, vector

How can I measure the closeness in the values of two vectors of different lengths ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for distance of two vectors of different length is explained here:
[Calculate distance between two vectors of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314576/calculate-distance-between-two-vectors-of-different-length)